# Magento Identifier position - similar to ?tp=1 in Joomla

Tags: magento, layout, identifier

Does anybody know how can I find out the predefined identifiers and their position in the layout of a certain magento template?

I am having a big problem every time I want to add a new static block, since I do not know what are the available positions.

In other words I am looking for something like ?tp=1 that joomla has.

Thanks, 
George

Answer (score 3):

Just had this problem and here is the solution I've found.

1. log into the magento back-end admin
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.

*Remember to clear your cache*

source: https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-

Comment: Is there any way to set it up so that it only works when you pass it query string parameters (like Joomla's ?tp=1) so you only have to see it when you need it and not so it's always on?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Joombla, but you can "Turn on Template Path Hints" to identify blocks.